# "The only factor considered" — no subject?

Tags: grammaticality, modifiers

Is

> All this goes to show that the strength and presentation of an
>   argument should not be the only factor considered when evaluating
>   proposals and making decisions.

grammatically correct? Or is it problematic because "considered" does not have an implicit subject?

Comment: Hello, auntjamaymay, and thanks for visiting EL&U. At this site we favor questions and answers that provide some form of documentation for the issues that they raise or attempt to answer. In the case of your question, it would be helpful to know what rule of English you think the asserted absence of an implicit subject for _considered_ violates. Do you have in mind a reference work that warns against such omitted implicit subjects? Also (and along a separate line of thought), might there be an implicit subject here that you haven't identified?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the subject (inside the **that** clause) filleted out to make it clear.

> **the strength** and presentation **of an argument** [is] one factor that should be considered when making decisions etc..

The subject is described as one factor
...but then it says it shouldn't be the only factor.
So, still inside the **that** clause, the explicit compound subject and its verb is:

> All this goes to show that: "**The strength and presentation of an
>   argument** should  [be a factor but **should] not be the only factor
>   considered** when evaluating proposals and making decisions."

Answer (score 0):

This sentence seems perfectly fine to me. I could not get what the problem with *considered* was. We often say 'These are the factors considered for credit rating' or 'These are the factors that *must be/are* **taken into consideration** while...'. If you really feel that a change is necessary, you can go for 'taken into consideration'.